# Generator Expression containing while loop and its statement

Tags: python, while-loop, expression, generator

Is it possible to write a generator expression which contains while loop and its statement? If yes, how is the template?
for example considering generator for Fibonacci series:

```py
def fibogen(m):
    n1 = 0
    n2 = 1
    while n1<=m:
        yield n1
        n1,n2 = n2, n2 + n1
fibseq = fibogen(30)
```

Is it possible to write it as a Generator Expression and if the answer is yes, so how? I tried it but couldn't do that:

`fiboseq = (n1 while n1<=m n1,n2 = n2, n2 + n1)`

Comment: Please update your question with the generator expression you wrote that didn't work.

Comment: Generator Expressions always use `for` and not `while`. `while` always is a statement, never an expression in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Not with a literal `while`, that syntax isn't supported. But you can simulate it with a `for` and an iterator:

```py
m = 30
fiboseq = (
    value
    for n1, n2 in [(0, 1)]
    for _ in iter(lambda: n1 <= m, False)
    for value in [n1]
    for n1, n2 in [(n2, n2 + n1)]
)

print(*fiboseq)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31-Qq2CoYG3ClZSblF6cWAjkaXApAUJaYU5oKZqXlFynkGeoo5BkpZOYpRGsY6CgYasbCpeJBopklqUUaOYm5SSmJVkDFCja2Crk6Cm6JOcWpmnCVYCPBZuQZxmI1Os8IzNYGCgJt0OTiKijKzCvR0II6ThPiZqjTYV4AAA)

Comment: Nice! If you don't need the first element of the sequence, you can even get rid of the `for value...` line and just yield `n1` instead, I think. (And in this case if you start with `(1, 0)` instead of `(0, 1)` that should be equivalent except for small `m`).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, there sure are some variations of this, especially for this particular example, where you can start further back like you said. My goal was just to show that `for _ ...` line as a general replacement for a hypothetical `while` clause, and I just made the rest work, didn't try to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the functional machinery from `itertools` to do things like
this too, if you like. Here is my silly one-liner:

```
from itertools import takewhile, accumulate, count
m = 1000
fiboseq = (n1 for (n1, n2) in takewhile(lambda t: t[0] <= m, accumulate(count(), func=lambda t, _: (t[1], t[0] + t[1]), initial=(0, 1))))
print(list(fiboseq))
```

with output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987]
```

However it's much better to just use exactly the generator function that you
wrote in your question!

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with a for-loop using some tricks:

```py
fibonacci = lambda m: (x1 := 0) or (x2 := 1) and ((next_x := x1 + x2) and (x1 := x2) + (x2 := next_x) for _ in range(m))

for num in fibonacci(30):
    print(num)
```

But with `while` it's not possible. Why do you even want to do that? It looks utterly ugly :)

Comment: No no they are asking for using `while` in generator expression. You are using `for` loop

Comment: Well, with `while` it's impossible, so I assumed, that he just wants a one-liner.

Comment: This produces too many values.

Comment: To elaborate on what the other commenters are saying: your code produces the first m Fibonacci numbers, rather than the Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to m, which is what OP was asking about. That's why the logic of a while loop was important!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Ah, you're right, I missed that.

Answer (score -1):

I know for sure that you are not allowed to use `while` in list comprehension, so I suppose the same is for generic expression

*Sorry, I guess my answer is better to put into comment section since it is not very comprehensive. But I don't have enough reputation yet*